# Polygon shapefile doesn't render certain polygons at full extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, display

This is a snapshot of a polygon in arc catalog, in preview mode. Even when brought into ArcMap, it won't display the polygons that are in the white space until you zoom in to an extent of 50,000 or less. I looked and there is nothing in the data frame properties to cause this and the scale range for this polygon is set to show layer at all scales. There aren't any definition queries either that would only display geologic units of certain types. Any clue on how to bring these polygons back from the void?  [image: polygon]

Comment: Did you try [repairing the geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm)?

Comment: Also, it might be a bad index, so try running [add spatial index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-spatial-index.htm) which should rebuild the index.

Comment: Tried both of those tools, neither worked. It's now telling me could not load data from the data source.

Comment: What data format is your spatial data?

Comment: It's a polygon feature class, within a feature dataset, within a file geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer really, but the problem is resolved. I had to export the line and polygon feature classes into shapefiles, delete all the polygons, import into a new geodatabase and construct polygons from the line feature class. The original database must have been corrupt.